# Filter for Duplicates or Highlight Unique Responses Across Multiple Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, duplicate, highlighting

I am trying to filter or highlight the results of a Survey with lots of response options, some of which repeat.

E.g. List your favorite animals

```
Name       B        C        D        E        F
Bob     Cat      Bird     Platypus Otter    Lion
Meg     Platypus Zebra    Bird     Lion     Ostrich
Joe     Panda    Giraffe  Dog      Platypus Platypus
Cole    Chicken  Platypus Zebra    Giraffe  Dog
Sally    Dog     Panda    Horse    Zebra    Snake
```

How could I filter everyone who said they like 'Dogs'? How would I filter for Sally & Cole? Or how would I have each repeated item highlighted a different color?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. How could I filter everyone who said they like 'Dogs'?

Here's how I do that:

[image: must love dogs]

Use a helper column with this formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,$G$1)>0,"yes","")`

This tests every response in that row for the value you enter in `G1`. This formula copies down. Filter on that column in order to find response sets that conform. Using just one helper column, you can change the value you're looking for to update your filter dynamically; if you like you could use many columns and treat the top row as fixed values.

## 2. How would I filter for Sally & Cole?

[Blind Spots' answer](https://superuser.com/a/1413528/701218) has these instructions. Highlight your data, add Filter, use Filter on the column you want to filter.

## 3. Or how would I have each repeated item highlighted a different color?

[image: conditional formatting]

This is actually a native option in conditional formatting. Select your data, pull down Conditional Formatting from the Home ribbon, choose 'Highlight Cells Rules', select 'Duplicate Values' and the popup box will allow you to choose the format to use for duplicate (or unique) values.

Comment: It's working ,, you get 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

> How would I filter for Sally & Cole?

1. Highlight the cells from A1 to F6 (all your data)
2. From the "Ribbon" select the "Data" menu then click "Filter"
3. Click the drop menu (down arrow/upside down triangle) in the cell A1 ("Name")
4. Uncheck "Select All" then check/select "Sally" and "Cole"
5. Click "OK"

Comment: It's a good start, but this only answers 1 of the 3 questions asked.